# How to count objects in JSON file

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to read a .json file and in my C# project and count the amount of objects inside an other object.

The .json file is fix and I'm not able to change anything from it.

e.g.

The .json file looks like this:

```
{
  "X": {
    "x": "...",
    "x1": "..."
  },
  "Y": {
    "y": { }
    "y1": { },
    "y2": { },
    "y3": { },
    "y4": { },
    "functiongroup": {
        "function1": {
            "A": "...",
            "B": "...",
            "C": "...",
            "D": "...",
            "subfunction": {
                "sub1": {
                    "a": "...",
                    "b": "...",
                    "c": "..."
                }
            }
        },
        "function2": {
            "A": "...",
            "B": "...",
            "C": "...",
            "D": "...",
            "subfunction": {
                "sub1": {
                    "a": "...",
                    "b": "...",
                    "c": "...",
                    "d": "..."
                },
                "sub2": {
                    "a": "...",
                    "b": "...",
                    "d": "..."
                },
                "sub3": {
                    "a": "...",
                    "b": "...",
                    "c": "..."
                }
            }
        },
        "function3": {
            "A": "...",
            "B": "...",
            "C": "...",
            "D": "...",
            "subfunction": {
                "sub1": {
                    "a": "...",
                    "b": "...",
                    "c": "...",
                    "d": "..."
                },
                "sub2": {
                    "a": "...",
                    "b": "...",
                    "d": "..."
                },
                "sub3": {
                    "a": "...",
                    "b": "...",
                    "c": "..."
                }
            }
        },
       "function2": {
            "A": "...",
            "B": "...",
            "C": "...",
            "D": "...",
            "subfunction": {
                "sub1": {
                    "a": "...",
                    "b": "...",
                    "c": "...",
                    "d": "..."
                },
                "sub2": {
                    "a": "...",
                    "b": "...",
                    "d": "..."
                },
                "sub3": {
                    "a": "...",
                    "b": "...",
                    "c": "...""
                },
                 sub4": {
                    "a": "...",
                    "b": "...",
                    "c": "..."
                }
            }
        }
    }
 
}
```

Now i want to know how many subfunctions there are in every function and print the amount in the Console.
So in the shown example it would look like this:

OUTPUT

```
1, 3, 3, 4
```

I´ve tried multiple variants like

```
var JsonFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"PathtoFile");

var token = JToken.Parse(JsonFile);
var FG = token.Value<JArray>("subfunction");
int count = FG.Count();

Console.WriteLine(count);
```

Comment: Based on the type names in the question, it looks like you're using Json.NET. This library also has its own tag that you can add if this is the case. Since the `using` directives aren't in your question, I can't be sure, so I won't add the tag myself.

Comment: HM it looks like you have properties instead of array items (in JSON array is denoted by `[` `]`)

Comment: Your file is not valid JSON. It must start either with `{` or `[` and it is missing some closing tags. Can you please provide a valid file?

Comment: what about parse json file as string and try to find amount of "subfunction" strings? yes, it may be tricky... but :)

Comment: @lufefon Could you please amend your question to post a **valid** json. [This website](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#) can help you to identify the problems with your current json.

Answer (score 1):

After fixing your sample json:

```json
{
  "X": {
    "x": "...",
    "x1": "..."
  },
  "Y": {
    "y": {

    },
    "y1": {

    },
    "y2": {

    },
    "y3": {

    },
    "y4": {

    },
    "functiongroup": {
      "function1": {
        "A": "...",
        "B": "...",
        "C": "...",
        "D": "...",
        "subfunction": {
          "sub1": {
            "a": "...",
            "b": "...",
            "c": "..."
          }
        }
      },
      "function2": {
        "A": "...",
        "B": "...",
        "C": "...",
        "D": "...",
        "subfunction": {
          "sub1": {
            "a": "...",
            "b": "...",
            "c": "...",
            "d": "..."
          },
          "sub2": {
            "a": "...",
            "b": "...",
            "d": "..."
          },
          "sub3": {
            "a": "...",
            "b": "...",
            "c": "..."
          }
        }
      },
      "function3": {
        "A": "...",
        "B": "...",
        "C": "...",
        "D": "...",
        "subfunction": {
          "sub1": {
            "a": "...",
            "b": "...",
            "c": "...",
            "d": "..."
          },
          "sub2": {
            "a": "...",
            "b": "...",
            "d": "..."
          },
          "sub3": {
            "a": "...",
            "b": "...",
            "c": "..."
          }
        }
      },
      "function4": {
        "A": "...",
        "B": "...",
        "C": "...",
        "D": "...",
        "subfunction": {
          "sub1": {
            "a": "...",
            "b": "...",
            "c": "...",
            "d": "..."
          },
          "sub2": {
            "a": "...",
            "b": "...",
            "d": "..."
          },
          "sub3": {
            "a": "...",
            "b": "...",
            "c": "..."
          },
          "sub4": {
            "a": "...",
            "b": "...",
            "c": "..."
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

you can retrieve the desired values like this:

```cs
JObject semiParsedJson = JObject.Parse(json);
var functionGroup = semiParsedJson["Y"]["functiongroup"];

for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
    var function = functionGroup[$"function{i}"];
    var subFunctions = function["subfunction"];
    Console.WriteLine(subFunctions.Count());
}
```

---

Please bear in mind that the indexer operator is fragile. Please prefer [TryGetValue](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_TryGetValue.htm) in production code to perform existence check before moving down the path.